# Using Array_merge for 2 for_each arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge, foreach, array-merge

Im using this to display a list of thumnails called from my cms:

```
<?php if($gallery_images) { ?>
<?php
$slide_page = 1;
foreach($gallery_images as $count => $image) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $image->getResizedImage(); ?>" rel="example1"  title="********"><img width="125" height="80" src="<?php echo $image->getThumbnailImage()     
?>" /></a></li>

     <?php if(($count+1) % 3 == 0) {
     $slide_page += 1;
      ?>
```

It calls images from within my CMS and displays them in groups of 3, with some added jquery to scroll through the sets.

What im trying to do is merge this with my videos within the same list.

The video code is as follows:

```
<?php foreach($videos as $count => $video) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $video->getLocation(); ?>" class="videolink"><img src="{thumbnail}" />Video A</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Ive tried using the array_merge function but seem to be having difficulties any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [`array_merge`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is pretty straightforward. You pass in any number of arrays and it will return one merged array. Please point out where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
foreach (array_merge($gallery_images, $videos) as $count => $value) { }
```

You may also want to look at [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

---

**Update:**

```
<? foreach (array_merge($images, $videos) as $key => $value): ?>
    <? if (is_object($value) === true): ?>
        <? if (method_exists($value, 'getLocation') === true): ?>
            <a href="<?= $video->getLocation(); ?>" class="videolink"><img src="{thumbnail}" />Video A</a>
        <? elseif (method_exists($value, 'getResizedImage') === true): ?>
            <a href="<?= $image->getResizedImage(); ?>" rel="example1"  title="***"><img width="125" height="80" src="<?= $image->getThumbnailImage(); ?>" /></a>
        <? endif; ?>
    <? endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @Christian: What is the problem then?

Comment: should of made things clearer, the issue is that the $value is different for both variables so $gallery_images - $image and $videos - $video as well as the the source of the thumbnail produced as images uses an thumbnail (so the image at hand however re-sized and the video will call an image from file, as cant produce a thumb from the same pretenses.